# Passing a func as an arg in another function of javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object, parameters

Here is my code :

```
//Player Loadout
//Version 1.0 by Madi Magdy

function Player(name,sex,side) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sex = sex;
    this.side = side;
}

//var newPlayer = new Player(prompt("Please enter your name"),prompt("Please enter your sex"),prompt("Please enter your nationality"));

//console.log("Hello " + newPlayer.name + "!");

function Class(classType,mainWeapon,sideWeapon) {
    this.classType = classType;
    this.mainWeapon = mainWeapon;
    this.sideWeapon = sideWeapon;
}
assaultClass = new Class("Assault","M416","M9");
engineerClass = new Class("Engineer","AK5C","P226");
reconClass = new Class("Recon","SRR61","Deagle44");
supportClass = new Class("Support","M249","M1911");

classChooser = function(playerChoice) {
    if (playerChoice === assaultClass.classType) {
        console.log("You chose the " + assaultClass.classType + " " + "class! Your default weapons are " + assaultClass.mainWeapon + " " + "and " + assaultClass.sideWeapon);
    }
    else if (playerChoice === engineerClass.classType) {
        console.log("You chose the " + engineerClass.classType + " " + "class! Your default weapons are " + engineerClass.mainWeapon + " " + "and " + engineerClass.sideWeapon);
    }
    else if (playerChoice === reconClass.classType) {
        console.log("You chose the " + reconClass.classType + " " + "class! Your default weapons are " + reconClass.mainWeapon + " " + "and " + reconClass.sideWeapon);
    }
    else if (playerChoice === supportClass.classType) {
        console.log("You chose the " + supportClass.classType + " " + "class! Your default weapons are " + supportClass.mainWeapon + " " + "and " + supportClass.sideWeapon);
    }


};

classChooser(prompt("Please choose your class! Type in Assault or Engineer or Recon or Support!"));


classWeapons = function(weapon,attach,camo) {
    this.weapon = weapon;
    this.attach = attach;
    this.camo = camo;
};

yourClassWeapons = new classWeapons(prompt("Choose your weapon"),prompt("Choose your weapon attachment"),prompt("Choose your camouflage color"));

var classChosen = function(yourChosenClass) {
    if (yourChosenClass === assaultClass.classType) {
        console.log("Your weapons are listed as follows");
        console.log(yourClassWeapons);
    }
    else {
        console.log("NOPE");
    }
};

classChosen(classChooser()); //I also tried classChosen(classChooser);
```

I enter the string "Assault" when prompted and when I try to pass the classChooser function as an argument in my classChosen function, the statement after the if never executes but the else does. What mistake do I have?

Comment: `classChooser` doesn't save anything. I think you should save the value from the `prompt("Please choose your class!...` then pass that into `classChosen`.

Comment: And how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you are not passing to `classChosen` what you think you are passing. The way it is, the variable `yourChosenClass` is `undefined`, which is why it isn't equal to `assaultClass.classType`.

You need to either store the value that the player chose, or return it from `classChooser`. Also, it would be much better for your code if the prompt for `classChooser` was part of the function instead of being passed as a parameter. So it could be something like this:

```
classChooser = function() {
    var playerChoice = prompt("Please choose your class! Type in Assault or Engineer or Recon or Support!");
    if (playerChoice === assaultClass.classType) {
        console.log("You chose the " + assaultClass.classType + " " + "class! Your default weapons are " + assaultClass.mainWeapon + " " + "and " + assaultClass.sideWeapon);
    }
    else if (playerChoice === engineerClass.classType) {
        console.log("You chose the " + engineerClass.classType + " " + "class! Your default weapons are " + engineerClass.mainWeapon + " " + "and " + engineerClass.sideWeapon);
    }
    else if (playerChoice === reconClass.classType) {
        console.log("You chose the " + reconClass.classType + " " + "class! Your default weapons are " + reconClass.mainWeapon + " " + "and " + reconClass.sideWeapon);
    }
    else if (playerChoice === supportClass.classType) {
        console.log("You chose the " + supportClass.classType + " " + "class! Your default weapons are " + supportClass.mainWeapon + " " + "and " + supportClass.sideWeapon);
    }
    return playerChoice;
};

classChosen(classChooser());
// or...
// var playerChosenClass = classChooser();
// classChosen(playerChosenClass);
```

Additionally, choosing the weapon can be refactored in a similar way:

```
weaponChooser = function() {
    var weapon = prompt("Choose your weapon");
    var attachment = prompt("Choose your weapon attachment");
    var camo = prompt("Choose your camouflage color");
    return new classWeapons(weapon, attachment, camo);
}

yourClassWeapons = weaponChooser();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your *classChooser* function returns undefined, so in 
    classChosen(classChooser());
You pass in an argument parameter as undefined. That is else statement gets executed.

To make this work, you need to

```
classChooser = function(playerChoice) {
     var returnType;
     if (playerChoice === assaultClass.classType) {
         console.log("You chose the " + assaultClass.classType + " " + "class! Your default weapons are " + assaultClass.mainWeapon + " " + "and " + assaultClass.sideWeapon);
         return assaultClass.classType;
    }
    else if (playerChoice === engineerClass.classType) {
        console.log("You chose the " + engineerClass.classType + " " + "class! Your default weapons are " + engineerClass.mainWeapon + " " + "and " + engineerClass.sideWeapon);
        returnType = engineerClass.classType;
    }
    else if (playerChoice === reconClass.classType) {
        console.log("You chose the " + reconClass.classType + " " + "class! Your default weapons are " + reconClass.mainWeapon + " " + "and " + reconClass.sideWeapon);

        returnType = reconClass.classType;
    }
    else if (playerChoice === supportClass.classType) {
        console.log("You chose the " + supportClass.classType + " " + "class!     Your default weapons are " + supportClass.mainWeapon + " " + "and " + supportClass.sideWeapon);
        returnType = supportClass.classType;

    }
    return returnType;
};
classChoosen(classChooser(prompt("Please choose your class! Type in Assault or Engineer or Recon or Support!")));
```